# What does a segmentation fault on modulus servers mean ?

Tags: node.js, modulus.io

I am getting the following error in the logs in modulus. Can anybody tell me what is wrong ?

```
Found package.json: ./package.json
Initializing Node.js 4.0.0
Now using node v4.0.0
Running command: node  server.js
/opt/modulus/bin/start: line 106: 20187 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $TORUN
```

Can anybody suggest a fix ?